# Delete range records at once - mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to delete the 50% records of a MongoDB collection and lets say the we want to delete the oldest ones.

So I have this script:

```
var count = Twitter_tweets.find().count();
var limit = Math.round(count *.5);
var tweets = Twitter_tweets.find().sort({$natural:1}).limit(limit);

_.each(tweets,function(tweet){
    Twitter_tweets.delete({_id : tweet._id});
});
```

But I'm using a each, since I don't know how to delete all records in one instruction, and I can't find that information on Google, how can achieve that with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to convert this into Meteor code exactly, but here's an idea for an approach:

```
var count = Twitter_tweets.find().count();
var limit = Math.round(count * .5);
var tweet = Twitter_tweets.find().sort({_id: 1}).skip(limit).limit(1).fetch()[0];

Twitter_tweets.remove({_id: { $lt: tweet._id } });
```

The idea is to get the `_id` of the document that is right in the middle of the collection and then delete all the documents that have a lower `_id`. Unless funny things were done, the `_id` will usually be a monotonically increasing value.

Comment: so lets see that you want to remove from 50% to 55% you will have to get both numbers and then apply `$lt` and `$gt `tweet._id` ??

Comment: You're saying that you'd like to delete the youngest 5% of your documents which are older than at least half of your documents? Like the `*` in this line: `|----------*---------|` If this is the case, then yes, getting an upper limit and lower limit and then removing based on `$gt` and `$lt` should work.